# pass sms:?body=xyz to default browser in android webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I Am Using Webview For Display html page
page have link like

`<a href="sms:body=xym">Forward</a>`

Which Working Fine In Opera And Default Browser
But Not Working In Application using webview

I Try below code but not working

```
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView myWebView, String url) {
        if (url != null && url.startsWith("sms:?")) {
            myWebView.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in your code.

It should be

```
if (url != null && url.startsWith("sms")) {
```

Also: If you have power over the webpage you are displaying you might want to include the phonegap library if you haven't already. That is meant to handle exactly those things.

Comment: try including phonegap. then there should be no problem. also you dont need the shouldoverrideurlloading method then. What permissions have you set in your manifest? you might need: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a separate SMS intent with proper type and give SMS write permissions to the application.

```
Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
smsIntent.putExtra("address", "Phone number scrapped from url");
smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body","Body of Message scrapped from url");
startActivity(smsIntent);
```